# Inline onclick event returns a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( " error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that works outside of this, but I really want to replicate the actions with just a normal div. I can do so by just adding this clickhandler:

```
 editor.insertText("\"≥\"");
```

to an onclick event. I want to add that snippet to an inline div but I keep getting an "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`" error from the below div:

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height: 50px;" onclick='function () { editor.insertText(\\≥\\); }'></div>
```

......What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add your code as well, what works and what not?

Comment: Syntax error: should be `editor.insertText("\"≥\"");` (if you want the quotes in the output) or simply `editor.insertText("≥");` otherwise.

Comment: inline style and inline javascript... just beautiful

Comment: seriously though, take a look http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height: 50px;" onclick='editor.insertText("\"≥\"");'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to Invoke the function, if you are including the function directly in onclick attribute, you have to use immediate function like this, though below you have to define what editor is first

```
<div style="background-color:red; width:50px; height: 50px;" onclick='(function () { editor.insertText("\\≥\\"); }());'></div>
```